# Can the Visual Studio properties editor reference a property to component in another form (or class)?

Tags: visual-studio, design-time

As a Delphi developer moving to .NET  I'm expecting similar concept like TDataModule & TForm to be available.  However, I could not find way to make a reference from a component on a Form to another component on another Form (or Component) class.

I understand technical difference underlying the issue. Delphi component architecture is based on component-streaming (resource serialization), but .NET form is actually a code generator. If it's not possible to do such thing; I wonder how typically, form UI designer put common component into the same place ?  Does it always have to be implemented in code only ?

For a bit more specific to what I'm trying to accomplish; I'm using DevExpress XtraGrid for which multiple instance of grids can reference to common "ExternalRepository"   How can the grids in separated forms reference to the same instance of ExternalRepository ?  Setting this property via code is completely eliminate grid design-time capabilities.

Any trick here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered by DevExpress Forum

> Sorry, but it seams like it is not
>   possible. You will find some
>   explaination about this in this
>   support center issue:
>
> Can the same PersistentRepository be
>   linked to many GridControls in
>   different forms in design time?
>
> http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DQ11884.aspx
>
> Short answer: only possible at
>   runtime.
>
> Regards,
>   Marc Greiner [DX-Squad]